# Siddhi CEP pattern for every event with occurrences

Tags: wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

I am writing a pattern in Siddhi CEP like -

"from every e1=inputStream[(e1.name == 'A')]<2> -> e2=inputStream[(e2.name == 'B')<2:> within 10 seconds select 'rule1' as ruleId insert into outputStream"

The above query only executes once when I pass AABB into the stream, and then nothing happened after that. Even I pass AABB again.

When I write this -

"from every e1=inputStream[(e1.name == 'A')] -> e2=inputStream[(e2.name == 'B')<2:> within 10 seconds select 'ruel2' as ruleId insert into outputStream"

The above query works well for each ABB pattern.

Is there a way to achieve AAB and then pattern should start from next upcoming AAB when the window time expires.

Comment: Are you trying to limit the pattern matching? such as it should match only once during the time window?

Comment: I am not trying to limit the output. I am trying to make a pattern like this "from every e =inputStream[name == 'A']<2> within 10 sec select e.type into outputStream" . Its only generate signal when AA comes only once, not after that. eg. I have the upcoming event like AABAAAA. It should generate 3 signals but it only generate 1.